# Run multiple lines of code but stop on error in R (from RStudio)?

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a very long, very delicate script, and I'd like to run each successive line of code ***only*** if the previous line succeeded (i.e. didn't error). If *any* line errors, code execution should cease immediately. Is there any keyboard shortcut inside RStudio that allows us to achieve this (e.g. similar to command + enter, but stopping on error) ?

#### Example and desired output

If we highlight these lines of code and run them (in either RStudio or R elsewhere, e.g. in the terminal)

```
2 * 2
b * 5
4 * 4
7 * 1
```

we see

```
> 2 * 2
[1] 4
> b * 5
Error: object 'b' not found
> 4 * 4
[1] 16
> 7 * 1
[1] 7
```

I would like some way such that I would only see

```
> 2 * 2
[1] 4
> b * 5
Error: object 'b' not found
```

i.e. code execution stopped at the first error

#### Notes

I will try to solve this without altering the code itself, preferably with a keyboard shortcut inside RStudio, but am very open to other ideas, e.g setting an option (`options()`)

Comment: Here's a more rigorous answer/solution that I saw, may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55043745/how-to-make-r-stop-when-meeting-error-or-warning?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (or Mac equivalent, <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) to run a script stops at the first error, so that could be a simple solution.