# Making R script continue running despite encountering error

Tags: r, rstudio

RStudio seems to be stopping running a script when it encounters an error.

This seems to be the opposite of what others have found (and what I've found in the past, where R continues despite encountering errors): [Run multiple lines of code but stop on error in R (from RStudio)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59811842/run-multiple-lines-of-code-but-stop-on-error-in-r-from-rstudio)

For example, when I run this:

```
2 * 2
b * 5
4 * 4
7 * 1
```

I get this:

```
> 2 * 2
[1] 4
> b * 5
Error: object 'b' not found
>
```

Any ideas why? I've tried restarting R, restarting my computer, and re-downloading R. I updated my RStudio a few weeks back, but I just noticed this issue today. I'd like the script to continue running even if it encounters errors.

Comment: Consider the `tryCatch` function

Comment: Thanks, @Julien. Does your R instance show the same behavior as mine? I've used tryCatch before when nesting within a function that might produce errors, but the issue I'm having seems to be with general R behavior, not a single function.

Comment: It's a normal behviour : when a script encounters an error, it stops by default

Comment: But it recently didn't used to be a normal behavior, I believe. For example, this post wants to achieve this behavior: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59811842/run-multiple-lines-of-code-but-stop-on-error-in-r-from-rstudio

Comment: I've also encountered this problem very recently, and it has broken a lot of my old scripts. This is definitely not normal behaviour.

Comment: Good to know, @FredrikH-R. Should I put a bounty on this question? My guess is this is an update in R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22) -- "Vigorous Calisthenics".

Comment: A bounty might attract some more attention i guess. I first discovered it on the Rstudio 2022.02.3-492 update (although it could be from a previous version), as i do not update regularly), and the problem persists on the 2022.07.1-554 update. I can't recall when base R was last updated, but i run the 4.2.1 version, so 4.2 could indeed be where things got broken. For Rstudio, there might be a bug in the On Error setting under the Debug menu, as changing them seems to have no effect on error handling (if the issue isn't with R itself).

Answer (score 4):

This behavior is intentional; it's a new feature in RStudio, so the only way to disable it is to use an old version. Read more about it here:

https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/3014

You're not alone in wanting the old behavior back; lots of people prefer it and have asked for the option to restore it. Please comment/upvote this issue:

https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/10391

Comment: Ach that's too bad! Thanks for the good answer, @Jonathan.