# Force R to continue the execution of a script even if an error was encountered

Tags: r

I am currently attempting to run data extraction on an HPC cluster, which means I do not have the hand on the R version or on the packages versions that are installed.

I unfortunately deal with the following issue with the `terra` package: https://github.com/rspatial/terra/issues/837 . To make it short, the function runs fine, I get back the output of the function, but it still throws an error even though it shouldn't, and this stops completely my runs on the HPC.

Therefore, I need quick way to force R to still continue the execution of my script. Given the very specific error I'm facing, wrapping my function call into `try()` does not solve the issue (hence, the solution here does not work for me: [R Script - How to Continue Code Execution on Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852406/r-script-how-to-continue-code-execution-on-error?noredirect=1&lq=1)), and my script still stops, so I cannot use that. Ideally, I am looking to call `options()` at the beginning of my script and change the right option so that errors do not stop execution anymore. I am also also aware of a similar question, but it focused on RStudio, which i am not using the HPC, so I can't base on it to solve my problem ([How to make R by default not stopping when an error is encountered while running a code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73567974/how-to-make-r-by-default-not-stopping-when-an-error-is-encountered-while-running))

How can I alter my script to force execution despite errors being thrown out?

Comment: Have you installed the latest version of Rcpp as suggested in the github issue you linked?

Comment: it is unclear why `try()` with respective `options()` does not solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

These are error *messages*, not errors in the sense that they do *not* interrupt an R script. Why are you concerned about them?

The messages go away when you install the latest version of Rcpp. Being on an HPC does not generally mean you cannot install your own R packages. Have you tried?

Comment: I've seen in the logs my runs were stopped when these errors occurred. I just tried to install the latest Rcpp and I don't have the authorizations to install new packages - I'd need to contact the assistance of the HPC so that they do it.

Comment: You would be the first one to encounter/report that; that is why I doubt it (except in a new Rstudio version, but you would not be using that on HPC).