# R script/function not interrupted when Error (only warning message instead)

Tags: r, error-handling, rstudio, warnings

Since my last computer update, when I am running scripts in Rstudio, errors do not cause interruption in the execution (for example : if a `stopifnot`condition in a function call is not met, the execution is not interrupted !), but instead raise warnings (with a warning message `Warning: Error [...]`. I find this behaviour very dangerous, and would like to restore the previous behaviour, but I did not find how to do it.

Does anyone know what happens and how I could force errors to interrupt the function/script ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: check with options()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make RStudio stop when meeting error or warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55043745/how-to-make-rstudio-stop-when-meeting-error-or-warning)